# Accidentally deleted file?

Tags: bash

I wanted to move the contents of a folder to its parent folder, and ran:

```bash
mv * ..
```

Now I cannot find the files and folders anywhere.

Is there a way to recover the data?

Comment: you just moved them to upper folder. Try `ls ..`

Comment: That was my intention. But the folder itself is empty, and the parent folder contains nothing (except the folder).

Comment: Ah, I solved the mystery. The folder itself is a symlink, and (evidently) the command moved the item to the parent of the *source*. Unexpected (to me), but I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0):

you can find your files with this command `find / -type f -name file_name`.
replace `file_name` with a file what you know its name.
after run this command, you can find all paths for `file_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Stop unnecessary activity in that windows, and try to find out what command exactly you executed.
Explore the content of the terminal window first.

I assume you do not see the files in the parent directory (use another window for the exploration.)

I your terminal healthy? (I will assume that it is but be observant how it responds to your keys.)

Use up-arrow to find the command, and check its content by left and right arrows. Any spaces after `..` ? Does right/left arrow always move the cursors by 1 character?

Type `alias mv` and if there is no output also `which mv`.

Type `history 5` and explore the output. Consider `history 6| od -c > file1` or `history 7 | od -x > file2` and look at the output (in other window).

Were there any character around `..` ? (If yes, explore carefully the content of current directory, may be `ls -la > file3` There might be file `xxx<hardspace>..` or `..<hardspace>`.)
Did you have any file whose names started with `-t` ? (If this is the case, consult `man mv` for option `-t`.) Likewise with other filenames starting with `-`.

Check if you entered the directory using a symbolic link. Maybe use `cd -`,
then find your previous `cd` command, remove trailing backslashes and prepend `ls -ld` . Does the output contain `->`.  If this is the case, you and your shell might have different idea about `..` from what `mv` considers to be `..`.
(Return by `cd -`)

Write `echo`  in front of the command. Consider pressing enter (take care, this is dangerous, but should be safe if you have only `mv * ..` watch out for any non-alphabetic characters, like ``` ; $ `` ( ) ```).